# Logging a right click with spock-geb?

Tags: grails, spock, geb

I need to test a right click on a map to drop a marker with Geb. I haven't found any documentation saying how to do this. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [drag and drop support](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/navigator.html#drag_and_drop) in Geb for that. There is [contextClick()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#contextClick%28%29) method available on Actions that you could use to a simulate right click.